# Search for duplicates in relevant sites

Tags: feature-request, search

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749956/continue-executing-a-program-after-end-of-ssh) and I searched for duplicates when I typed the title and got nothing (I should go to google, since I had a hunch that my question might already had an answer in *askubuntu*, but then I said, well, my question is not about ubuntu only, but for linux in general, so let's post the question - bad act from me, but with the average SO user to be with 1 reputation, I think I am not the only one who did that).

So, guess what, my question was *completely* answered in askubuntu, but I couldn't even mark it as a duplicate, because [it was from another site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749956/continue-executing-a-program-after-end-of-ssh/31750222#31750222) from SO.

---

Long story short: ***I am suggesting to search for duplicates when typing the title of a question, in other relevant sites of SO, such as askubuntu.***

Of course not it all sites, for example the aviation site is really cool, but I doubt that we can find a duplicate there!

Comment: I would question if that question is on topic on SO. Certainly, ssh-ing to a box is a programmers task, the same as any remote Linux/Mac user.

Comment: You might a have a point @Braiam, but this answers my question? It could..

Comment: Would be interesting for some topics on some stack exchange sites. I'm seeing duplicate questions and answers on the top of batch files between stackoverflow and superuser.

Comment: Your SO question belongs on Unix & Linux (http://linux.stackexchange.com/), or Superuser.  I tend to think of askubuntu as focusing more on GUI desktop stuff, and on Ubuntu/Debian packages specifically.  (And also a large element of less-technical questions from beginners that need help with basics, which is useful but not what I'm personally interested in looking at.  IDK why there's a separate askubuntu and also unix/linux, but for example I think shell scripting questions should all be on the Unix site, so they're all in one place.  People keep posting them on SO, though. :/)

Comment: Related (not a duplicate) [What to do with cross-site duplicates?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/280467)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it'd be great to search for duplicates across sites.  Unix scripting (bash/bourne shell/sed/awk/cut/sort/etc.) questions are scattered over [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), and [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).  Probably also Superuser.  I [posted about this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/13868/116941) (in response to [are-bash-shell-scripting-questions-on-topic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13807/are-bash-shell-scripting-questions-on-topic) on meta-askubuntu).

I'm sure the same questions get asked about that subject on every possible site.  Since duplicate-search, and the related-questions sidebar, aren't cross-site, we're missing out on finding stuff.  The gist of my meta-askubuntu post was that unless we had much better cross-site functionality, we should try to have all the questions on a topic on a single site (in this case, Unix & Linux stackexchange.)

Shell-scripting might be a poor example, since question titles are often really specific to the OPs task, rather than how they're going about it.  The same question about how to structure a  `command | while read; do ...; done` loop gets asked over and over again as "How do I do ", where x is some specific task.

Answer (score 1):

Advantages:

- It reduces the number of straight forward questions on SO whose answers are already there somewhere on the Internet and can be easily found by Google search. Easier management of data.
- A SO user doesn't need to search the internet for answers. SO, becomes one-stop for searching links to the answers. Increases visitors for SO (Profit).

Disadvantages:

- There are so many sites popping up everyday to provide answers to such question. How many sites will the SO keep a track of? AskUbuntu is just one of them. Assuming that the performance will take time to improve, initially, the site might become really slow because of this feature. (Not very serious consequence if it is perfectly coded at the first shot)
- The pool of questions on SO will reduce because question might have been already answered on some other website. In such a scenario, although SO will be the first stop for finding answers, but its user retention time will reduce as the user will go to another site for answers from SO. Lets say a competitor of SO comes up and SO providing the link to its answer. (Loss)
- Also, if website search is being included on the Question Add page, it will have to be included while search the question as well. Because if that functionality is not added while searching, when user tries to add a question, she will see that the question was already answered somewhere else, so why was it not displayed when she searched the answer.

So according to me, it might not be a very good idea to implement this feature as it reduces overall user time spent on the site. With time, SO might become more like another Search Engine to just find links.

Comment: most of your disadvantages seem to only be relevant if SO was linking to sites outside the Stack Exchange network.  Askubuntu is owned and operated by the same people who own and operate Stack Overflow. I don't think the suggestion was to link to other random sites like Quora or MetaOptimize