# Cross-site duplication marking

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

There was a question about something specific on MSE - [Close as duplicate in SE meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252287/close-as-duplicate-in-se-meta), but I would like a more general feature  that allows us to mark as a duplicate of a question in any site on the SE network.

One way to implement this, is that when we select *duplicate of...*, we would be allowed to paste a question from the entire network, and subsequent close review/voter-ers will see the marked question as an option.

There is plenty of overlap in the topics for some sites, and I do not see a downside for pointers on the network level to avoid data duplication.

Strongly related to: [Search for duplicates in relevant sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300598/search-for-duplicates-in-relevant-sites/300961#300961), but puts the onus on us the users rather then SE.

Meta SE strongly related question: [What to do with cross-site duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates) I do not think any answer there is good enough. **The accepted answer suggests a two step process, migrate, then mark as a duplicate.** Migration is hard enough, and I am sure the other site would not appreciate extra work. I think this feature request is adequate, and trust users enough to know if they have adequate knowledge to mark a duplicate.

**Note this solution does not affect the targeted site at all. "Different cultures" are irrelevant** - if we decide on SO that the another QA is a duplicate, then that is a good dup-target for us - and does not affect at all the other site. At worst it will throw some up-votes their way.

**What I currently do**: post a "cross-site duplicate of..." comment, sometimes I suggest deletion - I think the duplicate mechanism ("pointers") would be better.

**Addressing the answers and comments**

1) I agree in principle with [Renan's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382448/6881240) - we should be allowed to mark as duplicate questions from predefined sites we agree on. This may be harder to get going on, and I think our current 5-vote system will handle abuse anyway, so I find it a good suggestion, but second-order.

2) [yivi raised the concern](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382450/6881240) of user abuse to "force" migration, or a simple lack of expertise. I disagree the second is a valid point, since the same rules should apply as in-site dup-marking - if you are unsure/not an expert, leave it alone. Regarding abuse, I do not think it is prevalent on the site anyway, and the vote system should suffice as it always does. It may be worth it in the long-run to introduce adding the question to the other-site queue as well, so some (5?) votes are needed in both sites for such a marking? Note this is not really a migration, so should not "clutter" any other sites anyway, so I find it less important.

3) First point by [Joe W](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382446/cross-site-duplication-marking?noredirect=1#comment685075_382446), *what to do if the user is banned on the dup-target site*? My personal opinion, if the question in our site is quality, and so is the dup-target, then the ban on the other side should be irrelevent, and the duplicate mark allowed (so no special treatment).

4) Second point which I thought Joe meant, *what if the duplicate target is a different programming language*? This requires no special attention either, as it is the same for in-site duplicate targets - if the language does not matter, mark it as a dupe, otherwise it is not and answer it.

5) Third point by [Joe W](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382446/cross-site-duplication-marking?noredirect=1#comment685149_382446) - What about duplicates to Russian SO? I think it's safe to assume most of us know different speaking languages (I thought they meant programming languages, my bad) are not duplicates.

6) Apparently this is a cross site  duplicate of a request on meta SE! Addressing shog's answer from [meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16703/the-ability-to-link-cross-site-duplicates), *value for different answers from different perspectives*. This again,  in my opinion,  misses the point - if we on SO decide answers to a duplicate question on Sys Admins is a good fit, then that is already our perspective - someone answered the question properly, and there is no need for copy pasting the answers again.

Comment: Wouldn't that increase the willingness to post off-topic on stack sites because "someone stupid will link me an answer anyway"? just a off thought.

Comment: @Vulpex I do not think users who post the type of questions you are referring too have any idea of the intricacies of the SE. Most likely most of them guess where something will be on topic, and post there. This is meant for us, so we have a easy solution for cross-networking duplicate questions which are on-topic in multiple sites.

Comment: @Vulpex And if the question is not yet a duplicate and off-topic here, well we should migrate it if it's good for another site (both in terms of topic and quality).

Comment: You're probably right, it was just a thought that occured to me. Generally I agree with your suggestion.

Comment: possible cross-site duplicate of [What to do with cross-site duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates)

Comment: As an edge case how would you handle cross site duplicates where the user is on a network that blocks some of the stack exchange network sites. Or a situation where the cross site duplicate is posted on a site with a different user language such as the various Stack Overflow sites in different languages.

Comment: @JoeW The second is easy- just as if it was an in-site duplicate - if the language is unimportant, than mark it as a duplicate, if not than not. The first may be cause for debate, but in my opinion, if the question is good, and a good duplicate target exists, then the user ban on the second site should not matter, and I would allow it and mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: I will add both to the question.

Comment: @ahiijny I addressed my thoughts on the proposed workarounds to this feature in the question.

Comment: You are missing the issue. If the question is asked and answered on the Russian stackoverflow should it be used as a duplicate of a question on the English stackoverflow meaning that people have to run it through a translator?

Comment: Another comment to everyone - it seems disagreement relies mainly on abuse of mistrust in the user base, whether in terms of expertise or just something more blatant. I do not think that is a correct or fair premise.

Comment: @JoeW Actually, there already is some provision for "cross-language" duplicates of a sort. I remember getting a banner on a question on SO main saying something of the sort "this question has also been asked in SO Spanish", with a link to that (the same question, but in Spanish). Sadly I do not remember the question, and I guess the banner was shown to me because of geolocalization or browser settings or something like that.

Comment: It's been a difficult enough process to get users to research questions properly on a single site, let alone cross network. I don't think this is viable unless it's implemented with a cross network search, cross-network duplicate advice (for a user creating a question, the possible duplicates shown there) and cross-site moderators - all of which surely make the logistics a nightmare.

Comment: @Lewis I don't see your rational. I am not suggesting downvoting these questions,  or "punishing" in anyway if someone finds a duplicate on another site. This is just a method for us to link the questions (and provide the user with an answer!).

Comment: @kabanus I made no mention of downvoting or punishing. What I’m saying simply boils down to how much we expect of new users to the site. They are already expected to google their problem and check for existing questions on whatever stack they are posting on - what do you think will happen if they can’t search all stack sites at the same time but are expected to find dupes? Question quality will crash.

Comment: @Lewis What I mean is I do not expect raising the bar for new users.  This is just a tool for an experienced user if they see fit to use it. We should not expect new users more than we do today (Imo).

Comment: All you're suggestions are in fact great, but I try to make small requests, which are easiest to make happen.

Comment: @Lewis I don't see how this can affect the question quality. // If those things exists it would be good, but what's wrong if there's not?

Comment: @user202729 If a user is unlikely to even search say, StackOverflow for a duplicate, given how easy that is and how many times they are prompted to do so, it is even more unlikely that they will manually search each Network Site one by one. It’ll make the task of searching seem more intimidating to new users and they probably then won’t bother doing any. For example, think of cleaning your house. If it’s just one bedroom, you might do it. If you have to clean 3, plus kitchen, lounge... it seems like a much bigger task and you may not even bother starting.

Comment: @Lewis Oh, just use Google. (also, for some reason, currently Stack Overflow never says "use Google" or even "use a search engine", and only provides the users with the SO search feature (which some users complain for being bad).)

Comment: @user202729 Yeah, that's part of my point. There'd need to be further improvements across the board to make it work.

Comment: there's a feature request for this on meta SE, here's the more exact cross-site duplicate candidate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16703/the-ability-to-link-cross-site-duplicates

Comment: @ahiijny thanks for finding that, I wish we could close this as a duplicate! Seriously though,  thanks - I addressed Shog's answer on my last edit.

Answer (score 16):

I can agree with this if, instead of the whole network, you change it to related sites, which could be decided by each site's moderation.

I am active in World Building and we usually have questions that relate to physics, chemistry, earth sciences, and magic. For the former three, if the stacks for those topics indicate duplicates in WB, users are going to see some very funny answers... for the latter, people might be tempted to mark questions in WB as dupes from the RPG stack, even though the context of each stack is very different.

If mods or devs can indicate which stacks are related and therefore valid for duplication marking, then cross site marking could be a good idea.

Comment: I agree with this - I will address both answers in my question. On the other hand, I think if "grouping" is too much work for SE, I still trust users enough to not abuse the system to post to illogical sites (this would be the same for a bad in-site marking IMO).

Comment: There are actually frequent dupes I've seen between Movies and SciFi - sometimes somebody might ask a question on one because and there is already an answer on the other. Happens a lot with some fiction that has both books and movies (e.g., Harry Potter), I can certainly see *some* sort of cross linking being useful. A lot less frequently there are cross-dupes from SO - to Software Engineering or occasionally to Math.

Answer (score 9):

At first this looked tempting, but in the end I believe this would not work well.

If something like this were possible, I can see arguments being had about questions that should be simply closed as off-topic (or migrated, at best) with some users preferring to dupe-close with a target in a different site.

Close-duping with the target in a different site discourage migration and closing by relevant reasons. Users should be encouraged to ask the question on the relevant site, and cross-close-duping goes against that.

Also, experts on Stack Overflow (topics and rules) are not necessarily experts on a different site. More often than not, will have close-vote privileges here but not on different sites.

We should stay with the current workflow:

- If a question that is asked on Stack Overflow is not on-topic for Stack Overflow, it should be closed.
- If it is a **really good question but it is off-topic here but on-topic somewhere else**, it should be migrated.
- If it's on-topic here, but a similar question was answered somewhere else where it was on-topic as well, it can be a answered here too.

I understand the concern about replicating content across the network, but as long as there is topicality overlap among the different sites, it's bound to happen. I rather we migrated more questions to related (but more specialized) sites if possible, but I understand that have many other ramifications that are not trivial to overcome.

Comment: Only the 3d point is relevant in my mind, as the others go without say. The last paragraph I think I disagree with, if I understood correctly. If a duplicate exists in a different site, are you suggesting a two step + migrate + let them dup-mark it?

Comment: Regarding the expertise, I do not think that is a valid point - it holds for in-site dup marking as well. If you are unsure, or not an expert - do not mark it. I do not think user abuse is prevalent. We could, however, add a requirement for getting a close voter from another site as a requirement as well? Like adding the question to the other-site queue as well as ours? That seems like it may be a lot of work though, and may be worth considering only if this gets implemented in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

A softer version of this could be to display cross-site links more prominently, per this feature request: [Display other SE site links in the linked questions sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59569/display-other-se-site-links-in-the-linked-questions-sidebar/). This would bring related/overlapping content into closer proximity without necessarily locking users out of answering the questions on any one particular site.

See also:

- Meta SE version of this feature request: [The ability to link cross-site duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16703/the-ability-to-link-cross-site-duplicates)
- Related discussion: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)
- Related suggestion (different problem, but some relevant discussion): [Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with "crossover questions" between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989/build-and-strengthen-the-stack-exchange-community-with-crossover-questions-bet)

Comment: Good suggestion if this feature doesn't go through,  but I still do not feel it is justified not allowing us to close "How do I do this with sed" as a duplicate of something on Unix exchange,  without allowing us prevention of copying (or reproducing exactly) one liners - just as one class  of examples.